# Can't upload mycookbook

Tags: linux, chef-infra, devops, automated-deploy

I'm currently working on chef for deployment automation, i' building a cookbook that depends on another cookbook that i have 
 already downloaded from the chef supermarket (the cookbook is database 6.1.1), and i did the depends and include_recipe parts, but still when i  upload my-cookbook this error came up

(the same thing happened when i tried to upload the database cookbook which apparently depends on another cookbook Postgresql which means i'm stuck in a loop of dependencies )
I appreciate the help !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Chef you are using, I suggest the --include-dependencies option when uploading.

(https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook.html)

-d, --include-dependencies
Ensure that when a cookbook has a dependency on one (or more) cookbooks, those cookbooks are also uploaded.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you will need to go through each of the dependencies and get them on your Chef server or where you store cookbooks (I only use server server) so that's the only one I'm familiar with.

Comment: This is correct for the very basic tutorials, but beyond those you'll want to use Berkshelf or the Policyfile system to take care of dependencies.